# Gnome custom keyboard shortcut for monitor brightness increase not working

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, brightness

In Ubuntu 22.04 I can control my external monitor using `ddccontrol`. To increase brightness by 5%, I can type `ddccontrol -r 0x10 -W 5 dev:/dev/i2c-6`. To decrease brightness by 5%, I can type `ddccontrol -r 0x10 -W -5 dev:/dev/i2c-6`. So that I can easily control brightness using my keyboard, I added two custom shortcuts via Gnome settings:

[image: screenshot of shortcut settings]

This is the configuration for the Monitor brightness down shortcut

[image: Monitor brightness down shortcut]

This is the configuration for the Monitor brightness up shortcut

[image: Monitor brightness up shortcut]

At first they weren't working, but I logged in and out of Gnome and then the Monitor brightness down shortcut started working. However, the monitor brightness up shortcut does not appear to be working. I can decrease the monitor brightness, but not increase it.

After further digging, I came across the following in the logs after I attempt to increase brightness:

```
Jun 24 07:14:22 phoenix gsd-media-keys[244128]: Failed to set new screen percentage: GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._gsd_5fpower_5fmanager_5ferror.Code1: No usable backlight could be found!
```

This is quite odd since the command for increasing brightness most certainly works from the command line. I suspect the system is intercepting the brightness increase keypress, but why would it not intercept the brightness decrease?

How can I figure out the best way to resolve this issue? I took a look at gsettings and did find a few things, but I'm not sure what these mean:

```
brad@phoenix:~ $ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screen-brightness-down
['']
brad@phoenix:~ $ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screen-brightness-up
['']
brad@phoenix:~ $ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screen-brightness-up-static
['XF86MonBrightnessUp']
brad@phoenix:~ $ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screen-brightness-down-static
['XF86MonBrightnessDown']
```

For what it's worth, `xev` does not appear to detect these keys (but does appear to detect `F1` and `F2`).